# refresh issue in sweetdevria

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

```
<ria:tabLayout id="lay"  height="1000px" width="100%" orientation="<%=TabLayoutTag.ORIENTATION_TOP%>"  stateful="false" > 

  <ria:tabContent label="Basic Details" url="${propertydesc}"  selected="false"   id="tab1" removable="false" tabSize="150px" stateful="false"></ria:tabContent>
    <ria:tabContent label="Additional Information" url="${element}"  selected="false"   id="tab3" removable="false" tabSize="100px" stateful="false"></ria:tabContent>
    <ria:tabContent label="Contact" url="${contact}" selected="true" asIframe="false"  preloaded="false" id="tab4" removable="false" tabSize="100px" stateful="false"></ria:tabContent>
    <ria:tabContent label="Asset Condition" url="${asset}" selected="false" id="tab5" removable="false" tabSize="150px" stateful="false"></ria:tabContent> 
    <ria:tabContent label="Running Cost" url="${runningcost}" selected="false" id="tab6" removable="false" tabSize="150px" stateful="false"></ria:tabContent>
   <ria:tabContent label="Valuation" url="${currentvaluation}" selected="false" id="tab7" removable="false" tabSize="150px" stateful="false"></ria:tabContent>
   <ria:tabContent label="Attachment" url="" selected="false" id="tab8" removable="false" tabSize="150px" stateful="false"></ria:tabContent>    

</ria:tabLayout>
```

I need to refresh a window everytime, when clicks on particular tab...can anyone give me solution for this..

Comment: java or javascript ? What is this layout ?

Comment: @fabSa layout used is java